# How to validate rejection sampling?

Tags: bayesian, sampling, density-function, accept-reject

What is a principled approach to validating samples generated from rejection sampling actually follow the target function?

I am looking for some thing more than a simple histogram + density plot.

#### Setup:

I have a target density function $f$ and a proposal function $g$. From this I generate samples $y$ using my rejection sampling algorithm. Is there a way to calculate how accurately $y$ follow the distribution $f$ (for arbitrary target function $f$)? Failing a precise calculation are there other/better plots than histograms + densities?

Comment: Haven't thought about how valid / principled this is, but you could simply divide your sample in 3 (or in general n) parts and re/mis-use Gelman Rubin?

Comment: You could use a KS test.